# C++ file handling: Garbage value showing up for total bytes in file and number of objects

Tags: c++

I'm learning file updating in file handling. When I implement the following code on Code::Blocks 20.03, I get the garbage values for:

```
cout<<"Number of objects = "<<n<<"\n";
cout<<"Total bytes in the file = "<<last<<"\n";
```

The rest if the program is working fine, i.e. I'm able to add and update the content, but the mentioned lines on line 52 to 57 are giving error, I've marked comments on right in the affected lines, I've commented out my trials/attempts too.
The stock.dat file had simply:

- aa 11 100
- bb 22 200
- cc 33 300

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
class inventory{
    char name[20];
    int code;
    float cost;
public:
    void readdata(){
        cout<<"\nEnter name: ";cin>>name;
        cout<<"\nEnter code: ";cin>>code;
        cout<<"\nEnter cost: ";cin>>cost;
    }
    void writedata(){
        cout<<setiosflags(ios::left)<<setw(10)<<name
            <<setiosflags(ios::right)<<setw(10)<<code
            <<setprecision(6)<<setw(10)<<cost<<endl;
    }
};
int main()
{
    inventory item;
    fstream inoutfile;

    inoutfile.open("stock.dat",ios::ate|ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
    inoutfile.seekg(0,ios::beg);  //goto start
    cout<<"Current contents of stock"<<"\n";
    while(inoutfile.read((char*)&item,sizeof(item))){
        item.writedata();
    }
    inoutfile.clear();

    /* ADDING ONE MORE ITEM */

    cout<<"\nAdd an item\n";
    item.readdata();
    char ch;
    cin.get(ch);
    inoutfile.write((char*)&item,sizeof(item));

    //display the appended file
    inoutfile.seekg(0);

    cout<<"Contents of appended file \n";
    while(inoutfile.read((char*)&item,sizeof(item))){
        item.writedata();
    }
    //inoutfile.seekg(0,ios::end);
    //find number of objects in file
    int last=inoutfile.tellg();                           // ERROR STARTS HERE MAYBE
    //cout<<inoutfile.tellg();
    int n=last/sizeof(item);                              //2ND RESPONSIBLE LINE

    cout<<"Number of objects = "<<n<<"\n";                //GARBAGE VALUE
    cout<<"Total bytes in the file = "<<last<<"\n";       //GARBAGE VALUE

    /* MODIFY THE DETAILS OF AN ITEM */

    cout<<"Enter object number to be updated\n";
    int object;
    cin>>object;
    cin.get(ch);
    int location = (object-1)*sizeof(item);

    if(inoutfile.eof())
        inoutfile.clear();

    inoutfile.seekp(location);
    cout<<"Enter new values of the object\n";
    item.readdata();
    cin.get(ch);
    inoutfile.write((char*)&item,sizeof(item))<<flush;

    /* SHOW UPDATED FILE */

    inoutfile.seekg(0); //goto start
    cout<<"Contents of updated file\n";
    while(inoutfile.read((char*)&item,sizeof(item))){
        item.writedata();
    }
    inoutfile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is your source file binary or text? You're reading it as a binary file but your example data appears to be text?

Comment: It's a binary file @AlanBirtles

Comment: IMHO, your best method for finding a file size is by using an Operating System function.  Operating Systems are designed to handle files.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews What do you think `fstream` does?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings I've had discrepancies between using `fstream::seek` to the end of the file to get the quantity versus using an operating system `stat` function.  But then, I don't use file sizes very often.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Yes, those two mean subtly different things. The OP's approach is correct for the task apparent, and assuredly uses OS support to achieve its goal.

Comment: thanks guys, will try and update!